# Spring integration custom processing step

Tags: java, spring-integration

I need to introduce processing step in spring integration something like that:

```
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;

public class SomeDocumentProcessingStep {

    public Message<MyDocument> process(Message<MyDocument> myMessage) {
        // do some manipulations with message like providing new headers;
        return resultingMessage;
    }
}
```

The question is how to include such processing step in spring integration configuration? I have something like that:

```
<int:chain input-channel="someInput" output-channel="someOutput">
    <!--Here I want to use my processing step class -->
    <!--Chain contains other processing steps like transformations -->
</int:chain>
```

One way on doing this if with `service-activator`, but then I need to send new message manually from my service. Something like this:

```
public class SomeService {
    private final MessageChannel outputChannel;
    private final MessagingTemplate template;
    // constructor ommited
    public void distribute(Message<MyDocument> message) {
        // do my manipulations
        template.send(outputChannel, resultingMessage);
    }
}
```

And configure it something like this:

```
<int:service-activator input-channel="someInput" ref="someService" method="distribute"/>
```

But I have a feeling that this is wrong approach. Is there a better way of doing that inside integration chain? I need this custom processing step that will be in the middle of processing of message. The usage of `<int:header-enricher>` is not sufficient for me as it only provide a way of creating headers one by one. I want to do it in one class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You go right way with the `<service-activator>` inside `chain` . Only the problem you are facing that you don’t need that channel on the `service-activator`. It is a chain - a single composite endpoint for a set of steps. So, you still have to send message somehow into that `someInput`, but that’s already will be an entry point for the whole chain. Please, read docs on the matter: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#chain

Comment: but the result of `service-activator` won't be passed to the `some-output` of the chain. But you give me an idea of adding custom `Transformer` on the chain.

Comment: That `some-output` gets the message from the last component in chain. Not sure what is in your mind about chain, that you treat it some other way...

Comment: `some-output` will get unmodified message. The same, that it was before entering `service-activator`. I need to deliver modified message to `some-output` (the `resultingMessage` from `service-activator` class). That won't happen if I don't send it manually from `service-activator`. And I can't modify message in `service-activator` as well as message is immutable. If I put my `service-activator` class to the chain I will receive 2 messages in `some-output`: 1 that is unmodified and 1 from manual step inside `service-activator`. I need only 1.

Comment: To make it clear: msg goes to `some-input` -> I need my custom modifications (and standard header-enrichers are not sufficient) -> I need that modified message to be delivered in `some-output`.

I can do it manually with `service-activator` (receive from `some-input` then send message manually to `some-output`). So the question is does more clear way exist in spring integration or not. Sorry for any confusion if question is not clear.

Comment: Ok! Now it’s unclear what is task then. The service activator method may return any message which will go to the next step in your flow. So, why just don’t build a new message and don’t return that one from the service method. Looks like everything is in a mess here : I can’t compile the problem.

Comment: So If I make my method on `service-activator` to return new instance that will automatically go to the next step in chain?

Comment: Correct. That's the main point of streaming with integration components. The simplest model for that is with the `java.util.function.Function.andThen()`